# how to prevent table from exceeding the viewport - react bootstrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm working on a react js project again after awhile. I need to show a table that won't exceed the viewport when the content has a very long string.

I tried the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55880445/1235167) successfully on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwpruvqb/) like in this code:

```
      <div className="simple-table">
        <Table striped bordered hover>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Nama Barang</th>
              <th>Jumlah</th>
              <th>Harga</th>
              <th>Subtotal</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Lolipop Strawberry</td>
              <td>20</td>
              <td>Rp 5.000</td>
              <td>Rp 100.000</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </div>
```

```
.simple-table {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.simple-table table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;  /* add table layout fixed */
  overflow: hidden; /* add overflow hidden */
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.simple-table > table td,
.simple-table > table th {
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
}
```

the result on jsfiddle:
[image: jsfiddle result]

but when I try to apply the same code on my react js project, the result is like this:
[image: react js result]

what am I doing wrong? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On jsfiddle word-wrap: break-word is applied, in your project - for some reason - not. You have to check why. Try to debug the application and look if the css rule is applied or not.

Answer (score 0):

it turns out I just needed to add a `white-space:normal` rule

```
.simple-table > Table th,
.simple-table > Table td {
  white-space:normal !important; /* added this */
  word-wrap: break-word !important;
}
```